# Re-use a form array multiple times

Tags: forms

I'm a little stuck here. I want to make a block with 4 upload fields. So i'm trying to set the keys in 1 form array with the name file_link.

When editing the block, I can see the 4 upload fields. But when i'm trying to save the block Drupal gives me an error: (*Notice: Undefined index: file_link in block_with_fields_block_save()*).

It seems something goes wrong in the block_save() function. Any idea how I can solve this? Here's my code:

```
function block_with_fields_block_configure($delta) {

$form = array();

switch($delta) {
    case 'test':
    $description = variable_get('description', array('value' => '', 'format' => NULL));
    $file_link = variable_get('file_link', array());

        $form['description'] = array(
            '#type' => 'text_format',
            '#title' => t('Text'),
            '#cols' => 60,
            '#rows' => 10,
            '#description' => t('WYSIWYG text block'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#format' => isset($description['format']) ? $description['format'] : NULL,
            '#default_value' => $description['value'],
        );
        $form['file_link'] ['first_field'] = array(
            '#tree' => TRUE,
            '#type'         => 'managed_file',
            '#title'        => t('1st file'),
            '#size'         => 60,
            '#description'  => t('Select your file'),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                                    'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                    'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                    ),
        );
        $form['file_link'] ['second_field'] = array(
            '#type'         => 'managed_file',
            '#title'        => t('File 2'),
            '#size'         => 60,
            '#description'  => t('Select another file'),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                                    'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                    'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                    ),
        );
        $form['file_link'] ['third_field'] = array(
            '#type'         => 'managed_file',
            '#title'        => t('File 3'),
            '#size'         => 60,
            '#description'  => t('Another one...'),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                                    'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                    'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                    ),
        );
        $form['file_link'] ['fourth_field'] = array(
            '#type'         => 'managed_file',
            '#title'        => t('File 4'),
            '#size'         => 60,
            '#description'  => t('Misc'),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                                    'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                    'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                    ),
        );
    break;

}
return $form;
}

function block_with_fields_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
switch($delta) {
    case 'test':
        variable_set('description', $edit['description']);
/** Line below caused notice */
        variable_set('file_link', $edit['file_link']);

$current = variable_get('file_link', NULL);
$current_fid = isset($current['report']['fid']) ? $current['report']['fid'] : NULL;

if ($current_fid) {
    if ($data['report']['fid'] != $current_fid) {

    $file = file_load($current_fid);
        if (is_object($file)) {
            file_usage_delete($file, 'block_with_fields', 'report');
            file_delete($file);
        }
    }
}

break;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Please use Drupal coding standards: two spaces, not tabs. Also, with :undefined index" you usually get line number. Can you please add a comment like "`// Line below caused notice`" to your code? Don't make us guess something you know.

Comment: Sorry Mołot, I added the comment in the code. I will also take a read on the Drupal coding standards.

Comment: While reading about Drupal's coding standards I notice I did some things totally wrong. Oops! I will try to correct the code asap.

Comment: Not sure if it will help or not, but it might be a good idea to put $form['file_link'] as a fieldset in your form declaration.

Comment: You may also want to install devel, then do a dpm ($edit) to see what your getting passed.

Comment: Drupal coding standards are not mandatory here - just helpful, because if you use them, your code looks familiar. And answer by Ankit Agrawal makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be of the 'file_link' element missing from the edit() array. The line where you have commented that the below line is causing issue, there you need to debug the edit array and make sure you are having the '**file_link**' element in that array, few things that can be done are:

- Debug the value of `$edit['file_link']);` using `dpm()` provided by the devel module, or just use the `print_r()` or so and make sure that you are getting the required value otherwise may the element you are trying to access is having different key and you can just check the complete edit() array.
- The variable 'file_link' whose value you are trying to set is the correct and the required variable, cross check the name of the variable.
- Create a check for the value before assigning or adding it to the variable to make sure that the values is available and to avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I normally check arrays with print_r() but this time it doesn't output anything at all. where do you want me to put it? Also, if I change `$form['file_link'] ['first_field']` to `$form['file_link']` then that field works fine. So it seems it doesn't seem to get the nested arrays of file_link.

Comment: @nerdrocker Check the value of edit array `print_r($edit);` and see if you are getting the required value or not. And the modification of file_link field in the form seems fine.

Comment: Sorry Ankit, whatever I try, print_r doesn't print anything. In other functions with other variables it does. I checked watchdog and I notice another error I didn't mentioned yet: `Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 173 of D:\App\wamp\www\testsite\includes\entity.inc).`

Comment: @nerdrocker I see .... But the error that you have mentioned in this question is only because of the `'file_link'` not present in the edit array and you were trying to use its value. You can add the new error as a separate question otherwise it will create issue for other trying to search for the same problem, however first google the error!

Comment: I don't understand that `$form['file_link']` works but `$form['file_link']['first_field']` doesn't

Comment: you're right. but I don't think this error is just the result of the edit array not being there/being empty. I just wanted to give you all the information i've got.

Comment: @nerdrocker Please once check the form api example (example module also provide nice example of it) and there you will get a idea of whats creating a problem in the above scenario. If the above resolves the primary issue than mark the answer as accepted so that it can help other looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I placed the #tree property wrong. As what Ayesh explained on the Drupal Forums:

Use of '#tree' property will make Drupal to put submitted values of child form elements into an array (instead of a flat single-level array). However, this '#tree' must go to the parent.

Add this right before any line that adds child elements to the $form['file_link'] array.

```
<?php
$form['file_link']  = array(
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
?>
```

After this, Drupal knows children of $form['file_link'] should have 'file_link' as its parent.

More information here:
http://ayesh.me/drupal-bad-practices#tree